# Run linux commands and get their output in Android app

Tags: java, android, linux, command-line

I want to run some linux commands in an android app that I'm creating. I was told that for root access, I need to run the command in the background to prevent the app from crashing. I created this asynctask method:

```
private class Startup extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        Process pr = null;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // this method is executed in a background thread
            // no problem calling su here
            String cmdString = "su";
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                rt.exec(cmdString);
                rt.exec("ip link set wlan0 address 00:80:48:BA:d1:30");
                rt.exec("ip link set wlan0 broadcast 00:80:48:BA:d1:30");
                pr = rt.exec("ip link show wlan0");

                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        pr.getInputStream()));

                String line = null;

                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    Log.d("my log", "" + line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

I want to know what the commands are outputting but it seems like every time I include that in the code (BufferReader) the app just freezes and nothing happens so I can't see if my commands are working effectively. How can I check the output from running my commands? Also, should all of this be in doInBackground()?

Comment: Just as a check, have you run these commands on device with `adb shell`?

Comment: I downloaded a terminal app on my android device and ran the commands and the commands do work. The last one should have output.

Comment: What is the return code of the first command? and are you sure `ip` is in the `PATH` of the app?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking? I want to app to execute the commands. The commands are the same that work in a linux terminal

Comment: It wold be easier to just use Stericson's [RootTools](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/wiki/Usage#Introduction). It provides a good framework for checking superuser access and possible BusyBox as well.

Comment: When in a bash shell, the interpreter is also doing some of the work for you such as searching through the contents of the directories specified in `PATH` to find a command that matches the one you typed. `Runtime.exec` doesn't have that feature built in so an absolute path to the program must be given.

Comment: are you sure about this? I did "ls" and I got the proper output. Also "su" works and prompts the user to grant the app root access.